# ionic sometimes not showing list items

Tags: angularjs, meteor, ionic-framework, angular-meteor

I have a strange problem with a mobile application built using Meteor + angular + ionic.

On one of the tabs I subscribe to the collection called `Contacts` and display the list of contacts in a `ionic` list:

```
<ion-list>
    <ion-item ng-repeat="contact in contacts" type="item-text-wrap">
        <strong>{{contact.name}}</strong>
    </ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

Here is what's in the controller for this tab:

```
$scope.contacts = $meteor.collection( Contacts );
```

And here's what I have in the `router` setup:

```
...
} ).state( 'tab.contacts', {
    url    : '/contacts',
    views  : {
        'tab-contacts': {
            templateUrl: 'templates/contacts/list.ng.html',
            controller : 'ContactsCtrl'
        }
    },
    resolve: {
        contacts: ['$meteor', function ( $meteor ) {
            return $meteor.subscribe( 'contacts' );
        }]
    }
} )
```

The problem is that, almost 8 times out of 10, when I open my application the list html elements are rendered but the `name` and every other contact details are empty as in the picture attached. It's just a list item but the contact itself is undefined:

[image: empty list of contacts]

The number of empty items matches the number of contacts but each contact in that list is null, undefined. I tried every possible trick to make it render correctly and it failed. The number of contacts being rendered are 90 so it's not a big list at all.

If I refresh the page of my app using the chrome usb inspector it renders correctly. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
resolve: {
    "contacts": ['$meteor', function ( $meteor ) {
        $meteor.subscribe( 'contacts' ).then(function(subscriptionHandle){
            return $meteor.collection( Contacts );
        })
    }]
}
```

And you don't need this in the controller now `$scope.contacts = $meteor.collection( Contacts );` The controller needs to look like this: `app.controller( "myCtrl", function( $scope, contacts ) { 
   code...
    }`

$scope.contacts will have the collection returned like that.

Hope it works.

Comment: `$scope.contacts` is undefined if I remove that from my controller.

Comment: contacts: under the resolve should be "contacts":    / I made an edit. Also your controller should look like this: "myCtrl", function( $scope, contacts ) {
   ... code
}

Comment: still undefined unfortunately. Thanks for helping though

Comment: I think the `resolve` bit should be moved inside `'tab-contacts': {` object. Will try this now.

Comment: Ahh, yes. It should be in the same scope where the controller parameter is. I have missed this one. Is it woking now?

Answer (score 0):

I am having similar problem but in my case first 3-4 records are shown properly but rest are shown like stacked bar and bar are empty. I have set another page showing details of record which shows after selecting item from list. After clicking on empty bar details are shown properly.
Base : ionic angular ver 7 on windows 10 and apk created by cordova from command prompt

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).